# How can I get request parameter value if value is hash symbol (#)

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following request url:

```
localhost:8080/MyApp/browse/alphabetical/result?startsWith=#&page=1&size=10&sort=title&order=asc
```

Notice the request parameter `"startsWith=#"`.

I am unable to get `"#"` as the value of the `'startsWith'` request parameter. Instead, I get an empty string ("") as the value of the `'startsWith'` request parameter. Is there any possible way to get `"#"` as the value of the request parameter?

THIS DOES NOT WORK: `${param.startsWith eq '#'}`

THIS WORKS: `${param.startsWith eq ''}`

If there is no way to handle this, I will have to resort to using `startsWith=0 ... startsWith=9` instead of `startsWith=#`, which I really don't want

Comment: `#` can not appear in the url as value of parameter because it has special meaning in the url syntax (it defines anchor). If you need parameter that contains `#`, you have to encode it (encoded value is: %23).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot send a `#` with query string like that. It won't be a part of query string.

Quoting [RFC - Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

You need to encode the parameters in query string, before sending request. For e.g., In a `JSP` page, you can use `<c:url>` JSTL tag:

```html
<c:url value="/MyApp/browse/alphabetical/result" var="url">
  <c:param name="startsWith" value="#" />
  <!-- Rest of the parameters -->
</c:url>
```

Comment: URLEncoder must be used to encode each parameter value separately. Not the whole query string. In a JSP, `<c:url value="/foo"><c:param name="startsWith" value="#"/></c:url>` does that automatically.