# Transferring json object from jsp to server

Tags: java, json, jsp, gson

I'm trying to retrieve data from my jsp, everything is fine but in the action when I debug I find that the data is not completed.

here is my json object when I alert it in my jsp:
http://imageshack.com/scaled/medium/818/azww.png

here is the debug information 
http://imageshack.com/scaled/medium/21/z742.png

For information when I delete the '#' character the information in debug works fine!

---

**FOUND ANSWER**

I used the encodeURIComponent to replace the special character :
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(myJsonObject);

Answer (score 0):

From the spec [RFC-Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

To send #key in the request, encode every request parameter separatedly using c:url

Refer this answer

[How can I get request parameter value if value is hash symbol (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164861/how-can-i-get-request-parameter-value-if-value-is-hash-symbol)

Comment: thanks for answering, this solution works fine, but i m looking for a way to encode the url with jquery, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your hash symbols ("#") with the unicode variant "\u0023".

Comment: Her is the information that i receive in the action "landmarkLine":"\u002334567" instead of "landmarkLine":"#34567"

Comment: Correct.  Then it is up to your backend to process unicode correctly.